# Making normal tableview cell's text to be on the top instead of being in the middle

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hey I need a fairly large cell to show my information, but when I put text in it, the text starts from middle weirdly, how can I make it so, that it starts from the top?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you that you use a custom UITableViewCell so you can place the elements wherever you need them to be. Here you have a couple of links that will help you do so:

[Custom UITableViewCell using Interface Builder](http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)

[Creating Custom UITableViewCell Using Interface Builder](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)

I hope it helps,

Regards